# SED usage and Regular expression

Tags: shell, unix

Can anyone explain the following command?
What happens if the same code is executed using grep?

```
sed 's/^.*-S[[:space:]]*\([^[:space:]]*\).*$/\1/'
```

Comment: `grep` doesn't do any substitution.

Comment: If the question here is what is that pattern matching then using a site like https://regex101.com/ or http://regexr.com/ is likely going to be helpful here as well as http://www.regular-expressions.info/ for learning all about regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a `sed` command, it replaces something like `-S paradox` (possibly with text on either side the material), with `paradox`.  (There must be a space after `paradox` for exactly the string `paradox` to be printed; if there are non-space characters immediately after the word, then those are included in the output too, up to the first space.) For example, the input line `someprog -x painter -S paradox file2 file93` yields `paradox`.

If you apply the expression to `grep`, then the `^` and the `$` lose their special meanings, and it looks for a line such as:

```
schemas/^semicolon-S(comma)$/(comma)/gratitude
```

In the `grep` context, the `\(` and `\)` do remember a pattern (and in the example line, that pattern corresponds to `(comma)` — to confuse you, and me).  The `\1` then refers to the previously remembered string, the second `(comma)` in the example.  You could drop all the parentheses in the sample line and it would be selected.  If your version of `grep` supports the `-o` option to output only the text that matches, you can see more clearly which parts of the sample line match the regex.